# split string into 2 lists python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

Splitting a string

1.) `a,b:i,c,d:i,e,f,g,h`

So, below is how a split should work:

- if `:i` is present, then anything before `:i` will be gone to `colon_i_list` as an item and if no `:i` is present then it will go to `non_colon_i_list`.

for eg-> `:i` is present at the end of `a,b`; so, `a,b` will go colon_i_list and `c,d` will also go to a list `colon_i_list` as :i is also present at the end of c,d and `e,f,g,h` will go to list `non_colon_i_list`.

```
colon_i_list = ['a,b','c,d']

non_colon_i_list = ['e,f,g,h']
```

2.) `a,b,c,d`

no :i is present here.

```
non_colon_i_list = ['a,b,c,d']
```

3.) `a,b,c,d,e,f:i`

```
colon_i_list = ['a,b,c,d,e,f']
```

Comment: I think you might want to change the input for clarification

Comment: Your first example contains `:i` twice, what's the logic there? Also, `:i_list` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: see edits, yes first example contains 2 :i's which means anything before :i's goes in colon list, so first time a,b is present and hence goes in colon_list then c,d is present before :i so it also goes in colon_list

Comment: But `c, d` is also after the first `:i`, so which one would you consider?

Comment: whenever :i is encountered anything before :i will go in colon list as one item. So first :i is after a,b so a,b will go first after that :i is after c,d it will go in the colon list

Comment: So you want to use an iterative approach on whatever is left after the first `:i` is encountered?

Comment: This is exactly what `string.split()` does... I don't get what is the problem here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, a simple `split` will go a long way:

```
>>> s = 'a,b:i,c,d:i,e,f,g,h'
>>> tokens = s.split(':i')
>>> col, noncol = tokens[:-1], tokens[-1:]
>>> col
['a,b', ',c,d']
>>> noncol
[',e,f,g,h']
```

In case 3, the unspecified "other" list will contain single empty string.

Comment: Better use `s.split(':i,')` with a comma to get rid of commas in the result.

Comment: @Cornholio no, because it won't work in case your `:i` is the last element (see case 3)

Comment: Ok, true! But then it's not what OP is asking for.

Comment: better way to split will be tokens = [x.strip(",") for x in s.split(':i')] in order  to avoid that comma thing

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your question though,

```
z="a,b:i,c,d:i,e,f,g,h"
p=z.count(':i')
x=z.split(":i")
non_colon_i_list=x[p:]
colon_i_list=x[:p]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'a,b:i,c,d:i,e,f,g,h'
colon_i_list, non_colon_i_list = a.rsplit(':i,',1)
colon_i_list = colon_i_list.split(':i,')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this is by firstly creating a list by splitting on ":i,".

":i," is preferable over ":i" because this would cause issues for the first (and other) examples because you would get something like this: ["a,b", ",c,d" (!! - Comma in advance)

```
lst = string.split(":i,")
```

Then:

```
col = lst[:-1]
non_col = lst[-1]
```

This works because everything before the last element must have been split by the token and therefore belongs to col. The only point you need to take care of is adding a comma to the string if the last element of the string is ":i" so that the token functions well.

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "a,b:i,c,d:i,e,f,g,h"
string2 = "a,b,c,d"
string3 = "a,b,c,d,e,f:i"

def print_strange_rule(string):
    str_list = string.split(",")
    colon_i_list = []
    non_colon_i_list = []

    token = ""
    for piece in str_list:
        if ":i" not in piece:
            token += piece + ","
        else:
            colon_i_list.append(token + piece[:-2])
            token = ""
    non_colon_i_list.append(token[:-1])

    print colon_i_list
    print non_colon_i_list

print_strange_rule(string1)
print_strange_rule(string2)
print_strange_rule(string3)
```

I think my answer is the worst among the previous 2 answers though...

Answer (score 0):

At first check if ':i' is in your string: if there isn't any :i so your okay to go and all of that string should be in non_colon_i_list. However, if there is a ':i' in your string, so split it by ':i' if length of answer is 1, all of that string should be in your colon_i list, else all of items except last one is in your colon_i list and just the last one should be in non_colon_i_list. see code below:

```
temp = 'a,b:i,c,d:i,e,f,g,h'
non_colon_i_list = []
colon_i_list = []
if ':i' not in temp:
   non_colon_i_list.append(temp)
else:
    splited = temp.split(':i')
    if len(splited) == 1:
        colon_i_list.append(splited[0])
    else:
        counter = 0
        while counter<len(splited)-1:
            colon_i_list.append(splited[counter])
            counter += 1
        non_colon_i_list.append(splited[-1])
```